# How to empty a GitHub Repository?

Tags: git, github

I want to delete all files in the remote repository and then push local files. How can I do that?

I don't want to push .exe files into GitHub, so I created `.gitignore`. But my GitHub repository already has some `.exe` files. I am planning to push only `.cpp` files. But first I want to delete all the `.exe` files or empty the repository.

Comment: Did you try to delete the files locally and push them again?

Comment: Yes, I deleted all .exe files locally. But if I `git push`, the remote repository will still have the exe files, right?

Comment: Nope, the remote should sync with your local repo, so the `.exe` files should be gone after your push. Just ensure that the deletion is also committed in the GIt history, so when pushing, Git will know that these files should be deleted

Comment: thanks, that worked for me. But is there any way to delete all the files on the GitHub repo in one go (on the website)?

Comment: Even if you delete files in the suggested manner, they still exist in the history of the repository. They are not gone for good and can be resurrected.

Comment: As @j6t suggested, I feel you're trying to rewrite the Git history? You can reset back to the previous commit and do a force push to rewrite it (but it's irreversible, so use at your own risk) or you can open a new repo and push to it.